# Create Temp folder , Copy Files , Process them and delete them when process is done

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project where i need to create temp folder ,copy files from a c:/folder with name abc , process them ( which is done using a internal dll) and after the process is done , delete that temp folder and files in that folder.

Can anyone check the template C# template below and see if i am right track.

```
  public void TemporaryDirectory()
{
  string tempFolder = Path.GetTempFileName();
  File.Delete(tempFolder);
  Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
string foldername = "c:\folder"
foreach(files in foldername)
{
  File.Copy(files,tempFolder);
}
 //Process Stuff

//once processing done
If(Process = done)
{
File.delete(tempFolder);
}
}
```

Comment: This is not code writing service. Show what you have done and where you need assistance.

Comment: @JohanP added template that i think can work. please check and see if i am on right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a class assignment, but I'll lead you in the right direction.

You'll be using System.IO for all of your files and directories. [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders) is a detailed guide for the same problem.

Comment: Thank you Chandler. This is very useful information.